# Transitive & symmetric relation; why is this wrong?

Tags: functions, relations

> "Give a relation that satifies the condition:"
>
> Symmetric and transitive but not reflexive.

This is what I gave:

> R = {(x,y), (y,z), (z,x), (y,x), (z,y), (x,z)}

I was told this was not transitive. However, my book's definition of transitive is the following:

> *R is transitive if for every x, y, and z, xRy and yRz implies xRz*

What did I do incorrectly?

Comment: You have $y R z$ and $z R y$, but not $y R y$.

Comment: I also have xRy and yRx, but no xRx... and zRx xRz, but not zRz. I assumed those are considered reflexive.. Would I need those as well?

Comment: If you had all these relations, $R$ would be both transitive and reflexive. Currently, it's neither.

Comment: Right, but I specifically can't have reflexive. I need Transitive and symmetric for this problem. Sorry, I'm just confused.

Comment: If this was transitive, since you have xRy and yRx, you would need to have xRx as well, but that would make it reflexive.

Comment: Okay, I'm beginning to see that. So with the example I provided (x, y, and z), is it _impossible_ to turn this into a both transitive and symmetric answer **without** being reflexive?

Comment: See the answer I just posted for possible help (and possible confusion. . . )

Comment: I have created a [canonical Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802279/), which is meant to address this question, and others like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use $\{a,b,c\}$ as the set your relation is over to avoid confusion with the $x,y,z$ in the definitions of reflexive, symmetric, transitive.  To be reflexive you would have to have $\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)\} \subset R$ Your relation corresponds to $\{(a,b),(b,a),(a,c)(c,a),(b,c),(c,b)\}$ so your relation is certainly not reflexive.  In the definition of transitive, it is not required that $x,y,z$ be distinct elements, so I can say that if the relation is transitive $(aRb\  \& \ bRa) \implies aRa$.  By inspection this is false, so the relation is not transitive.

To rescue this, assume $aRb$.  Then by symmetry you have $bRa$.  By transitivity, then we need $aRa$  Does this suggest a way out?

Comment: Is this a possible solution? R= {(a,b), (b, a), (a, a)}   It would seem to me this satisfies symmetric and transitive, but not reflexive as there is no (b,b).

Comment: No, because $(bRa\  \&\  aRb) \implies bRb$ so it is not transitive.  If you add $(b,b)$ to it you will be fine because you still don't have $(c,c)$.  But there is a simpler example...

Comment: Then unfortunately I'm unable to see the suggested way out..

Comment: What would you need to take away from the  relation you just gave to make sure it wasn't reflexive?

Comment: @Bonnaduck:  His relation, augmented by the required $(b,b)$ is still not reflexive.  In fact, that is an acceptable answer to the problem if the set the relation applies to is $\{a,b,c\}$

Comment: So I was overlooking something incredibly simple; relations don't have to use the entire domain.

Comment: @H4x0rjax: what saved us was not having $c$ related to anything.  Then we didn't get forced to have $(c,c)$ in the relation.  We can keep going down that path.  Yes, your last comment is correct.  You can have a relation where some element of the domain is not related to anything.

Comment: Ah. Great, thank you for the help!

Comment: @H4x0rjax:  the simplest answer is the empty relation.  Symmetric and transitive are of the form if (something is related) then (something else is related).  If nothing is related then this is true.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of confusing you even more, here is a well known fake theorem.

"**Theorem**". If a relation is symmetric and transitive, it **must** be reflexive.

"**Proof**".  Suppose $R$ is symmetric and transitive.  Take any element $x$.  Take an element $y$ such that $x\,R\,y$.  Since $R$ is symmetric we have $y\,R\,x$.  But then since $R$ is transitive and $x\,R\,y$ and $y\,R\,x$, we have $x\,R\,x$.  As this is true for all $x$, the relation $R$ is reflexive.

If you can figure out what is wrong with this argument, it may guide you in the direction of the example you need.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! It seems to me that there are very few cases where this will not be true, such as an empty relation..

Comment: Okay, is S the domain here? if so, is R just a set of mappings? what is the range?

Comment: @user3221706, well done - the empty relation is an answer (not the only example) - it **is** symmetric and transitive, though you will probably have to think carefully to see why.