# Working out if a given relation is reflexive, symmetric or transitive (or all 3?)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, integers

> On the set of integers, let  be related to  precisely when x ≠ y

1. Is this Reflexive?
2. Is this Symmetric?
3. Is this Transitive?

I'm also wondering if it can be multiple? I assume it can maybe be two but maybe not all 3.

To my understanding:

- Reflexive is when each element is related to itself, I am not sure
  how to apply that to x ≠ y? (**Edit:** If x = 3 and y = 3, then x ≠ y, so it can't be reflexive as it would be an incorrect statement, so for not equals to it can never be reflexive from what I studied going back over notes)
- Symmetric is when x is related to y, it implies that y is related to
  x (which may be fitting here as x is related to y when they don't
  equal each other?)
- Transitive: When x is related to y, and y is related to z, then x is
  related to z (Not applicable here? Unsure)

I'm not sure if it's reflex as x ∈ Z and y ∈ Z (both are related to the set of integers), it could be symmetric as they are related when x ≠ y is the same as being related when y ≠ x, then I'm not sure of transitive.

Comment: $x\ne x$ does not hold. Hence the relation is not reflexive. It is neither transitive since $x\ne y$ and $y\ne z$ does not imply $x\ne z$. But it is symmetric.

Comment: @Peter Thankyou for your response! I literally just refreshed after editing the reflexive part and hopefully I got the right understanding of why it can't be reflexive (as if y is the same value as x, then its incorrect) and also what you said x not being equal to x makes no sense either.

Comment: $(1)$ The relation is symmetric because $x\ne y$ implies $y\ne x$. $(2)$ For the reflexive part, you verify $x$~$x$ (here $x\ne x)$

Comment: @Peter Did you want to make a longer answer incorporating your two comments + a little bit more info so I can accept it as an answer? Your help has been amazing! :)

Comment: As an aside, not only is the given relation *not reflexive* (*meaning there is at least one example of an element who is not related to itself*)... an even stronger statement can be made here... that it is *irreflexive* (*meaning that all elements are examples of elements who are not related to themselves*).

Comment: "*I'm also wondering if it can be multiple? I assume it can maybe be two but maybe not all 3.*"  Relations may be *any* combination of these three properties, including all three.  Those relations who are all three (reflexive, symmetric, and transitive) are of particular importance in maths and are called "Equivalence Relations."

Comment: Is the question "Can a relation satisfy any combination of these three properties?"  If so, [this is a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3802279/).  On the other hand, if you are specifically interested in the relation $\{(x,y) : x\ne y\}$, that is a distinct question...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the relation is not relfexive.

Now, it is time to formally prove that.

To prove that it is not, you must prove that the statement "$\neq$ is a reflexive relation" is false.

First we use the definition of reflexivity to rewrite the above statement into:

$$\forall x\in Z: x\neq x$$

Now, we must prove the above statement is **false**. Since the statement is of the type "$\forall x\in X: P(x)$", it is enough to find **one** value of $x$ such that $P(x)$ is not true (this value is then called the *counterexample). In your case, taking $x=3$ is perfectly OK, because $3\neq 3$ is false.

---

Alternatively, you could just prove the negation of the statement. The negation is

$$\exists x\in Z: x=x$$

this statement can be proven, because $x=3$ satisfies the relation $x=x$.

---

For symmetry, you are correct that the relation **is** symmetric.

You can do this by proving the statement:

$$\forall x,y\in Z: x\neq y \implies y\neq y$$

Formally, can prove any statement of the type $\forall x,y\in A: P(x,y)\implies Q(x,y)$ by:

- Taking any two values $x,y\in A$
- Assuming $P(x,y)$ is true
- From that, proving $Q(x,y)$ must also be true.

Now, try it on your case!

---

For transitivity, if you think the relation is not transitive, then try to find some couterexample. Once you do, follow the steps I outlined above to formally prove the relation is not transitive.

- Assuming