# The practical use of reflexive relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I understand what reflexive relation on a set is, but I struggle to come up with a practical use of it - why would you even bother defining it?

I would really appreciate a couple examples, where reflexions are used, so it would be a little easier to understand - why they are needed?

Comment: By itself, reflexivity doesn't mean much. It usually is combined with other properties, like symmetry or transitivity, to make for interesting classes of relations. If I am going to speak loosely, though, reflexivity is often used to rule out pathological cases.

Comment: As an example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4706135/why-do-we-need-to-include-reflexivity-in-the-definition-of-an-equivalence-relati) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I saw your answer linked  in the comment above. It is something I never thought about. Thanks for your elucidation.

Comment: @PVanchinathan - Glad you liked it.